# How do I prevent a dialog from showing up?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-alertdialog

When I get a ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED from a BluetoothDevice which is not paired, a "Bluetooth pairing request" alertdialog turns up on the screen. How can I prevent this from happening? I don't want to pair or connect with the remote device, I just want to know that it's on and in range and I don't want to bother the user.

And in general, how can I find out if what I do programmatically could cause an unwanted dialog to pop up?

Could I programmatically be notifies if a dialog is displayed, and programmatically dismiss it?